# Lifetime Values by Creation Date in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I have a dataset that is the meta-data on facebook post; things like the number of clicks, interactions, and creation date for each post. I want to make a bar graph that shows the number of interactions by post, anchored by the creation date. EG, the lifetime number of interactions for all the post created in March 2019, April 2019, etc. The dataset has the daily value for each post, so i'm using a MAX aggregation to get the total number of clicks per post.

I'm trying to use level of detail to get the number of clicks per post, and then use a filter for the creation date.

`{INCLUDE [Post Id]: MAX([Clicks (Unique)])}`

However, when i do this, i get the same value for every month, which I know isn't correct. I'm fairly new to Tableau, so I'm wondering if I'm misunderstanding how to use LOD or if there is another way to do this.

Thanks

Comment: Hi welcome to SO.  Please include a brief snapshot of data (and if possible copy some data here as a code) and along with the desired output in respect of that sample data.

Comment: Thank you, as you noticed this is my first question, so I'm pretty new! It's work related, so i'll need to see what I can put in a snap shot (new job too) and update. Thanks for the comment/advice. 
J

Comment: If your data us sensitive enough you can replace that with some random sample values, just to illustrate your case.

Comment: Thanks , I found the problem, it was … User Error, there were several date fields representing different things and  i was using the wrong one. I appreciate the help, and that's a great idea about random values, I'll use that next time. Thanks!